# compile error: ld: file too small (length=15) file 'libpng.a'

Tags: compile

when I compile blender on mac, got

```
ld: file too small (length=15) file '/Users/dashuai/blender-git/lib/darwin/png/lib/libpng.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [bin/datatoc_icon] Error 1
make[2]: *** [source/blender/datatoc/CMakeFiles/datatoc_icon.dir/all] Error 2
```

my env:

- macos 13.4
- xcode 14.0
- blender branch: blender-v3.5-release

How can i fix this? thanks.

Comment: This is a Q&A site run by volunteers to help with problems using Blender. There are no Blender developers here and no-one here has any association with the Blender Foundation. Suggest you ask on https://devtalk.blender.org/ or post a bug report there.